# Bokeh inside Google Colab

Tags: python, jupyter, google-colaboratory

Matplotlib doesn't give me the visualisation I want

I like the interactive features of Bokeh and I would like to see if someone was able to get it running inside Google Colab?

I installed the library (from the notebook itself) and it showed the installation is successful

```
!pip install bokeh
```

but when I use it. It doesn't show anything (not even an error). Just blank output. When I check chrome's Javascript console, I see the follwoing

> Bokeh: ERROR: Unable to run BokehJS code because BokehJS library is
>   missing

Comment: and if someone with higher reputation can add the new tag 'google-colab', that would be better

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's a Bokeh sample in the [charts example notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=/v2/external/notebooks/charts.ipynb&scrollTo=JGnotb1n73Yk).

I suspect the important bit you'll need to add is:

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
output_notebook()
```

**And most importantly `output_notebook()` must be called inside the same cell**

Comment: This works with the pre installed version of bokeh, which 1.4.0 as of today. If we upgrade it to the latest 2.x version, it doesn't show any plot

Comment: With this in a normal notebook, no problem.  On Colab, it makes a big red block that reads "Bokeh Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'textContent') at embed_document...."

Answer (score 1):

I made a library to make it easier to use bokeh in Colab

First install it

```
!pip install kora
```

Then your can plot a figure easily

```py
from kora.bokeh import figure
p = figure(100, 200)  # h, w
p.line([1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 2, 4])
p # display itself, don't need show()
```

If you call `from kora import bokeh`, it can work the same as `import bokeh`. Or you can use them together as well. What I did is just create `_repr_html_()` that help display the Figure object.

Answer (score 0):

For bokeh above 2.x, to show bokeh plots in Google Colab

try

```
# Our main plotting package (must have explicit import of submodules)
import bokeh.io
import bokeh.plotting

# Enable viewing Bokeh plots in the notebook
bokeh.io.output_notebook()
```