# Bokeh interaction not norking inside Google Lab

Tags: python, bokeh, google-colaboratory

interact fonction seems not working either with Firefox or Chrome into Google Colab Python Jupyter notebook?
Any idea how to fix it ?
(related link [Bokeh inside Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48295229/bokeh-inside-google-colab))

Answer (score 0):

From from [bokeh team](https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/interact-inside-google-colab/5361)

*push_notebook does not function in Colab because Google actively blocks usage of notebook comms. Supposedly they are working to change this but we have no control over their schedule, so I can’t speculate when it might become available,*